# Laptop battery keeps discharging even after full charge (not switching to AC)

Tags: 16.04, laptop, power-management, battery, acpi

The laptop does not switch to AC mode after fully charging.
I dualboot and this problem is nonexistent on Windows 10.
But on Ubuntu 15.10 it just keeps discharging.

**Problem persists on Ubuntu 16.04 variants as well.**

I tried fully charging(which never actually happens as ubuntu always keeps showing discharging but I charged it upto as high as possible)
and then discharging to 0 and fully charging again. But it just does not work.

This cant be good for the battery, Please help.

```
upower --dump
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC0
  native-path:          AC0
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Thu 04 Feb 2016 08:10:34 PM BDT (90 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              yes
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               ASUSTeK
  model:                X550A30
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Thu 04 Feb 2016 08:10:55 PM BDT (69 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              37.095 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         38.49 Wh
    energy-full-design:  45 Wh
    energy-rate:         0.0192461 W
    voltage:             15 V
    percentage:          95%
    capacity:            85.5333%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (rate):
    1454595055  0.019   discharging
    1454595034  7.230   discharging
    1454595032  3.705   discharging

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Thu 04 Feb 2016 08:10:55 PM BDT (69 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  battery
    present:             yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              37.095 Wh
    energy-full:         38.49 Wh
    energy-rate:         0.0192461 W
    percentage:          95%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.99.3
  on-battery:      no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  critical-action: HybridSleep
```

ACPI output:

```
acpi -V
Battery 0: Discharging, 95%, discharging at zero rate - will never fully discharge.
Battery 0: design capacity 3000 mAh, last full capacity 2580 mAh = 86%
Adapter 0: on-line
Thermal 0: ok, 46.0 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 0 switches to mode critical at temperature 103.0 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 1 switches to mode passive at temperature 105.0 degrees C
Cooling 0: x86_pkg_temp no state information available
Cooling 1: intel_powerclamp no state information available
Cooling 2: LCD 7 of 10
Cooling 3: LCD 7 of 10
Cooling 4: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 5: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 6: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 7: Processor 0 of 3
```

I have tried removing TLP and using a fresh installation but still no luck, I hope my continued usge in this condition isn't killing the battery.

Comment: The problem persists in ubuntu 16.04 (Toshiba Satellite L15-B1330). Please, if someone finds a solution, inform us. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

The AC adaptor is showing online, and the battery is discharging at zero rate.

The battery charging logic is not under OS control. One of the many independent microcontrollers in your laptop controls the battery (along with a corresponding microcontroller in the battery itself) decide when and how to charge. At worst, your OS would not be correctly interpreting the status that they report, but I wouldn't worry about the battery being ruined.

PS: If you are plugged in it *does* stay charged, right, it doesn't discharge?

Comment: It's microcontrollers all the way down :)

Comment: As you say, the battery is kept charged. Thanks for your answer. I hope they keep the laptop plugged does not affect battery life. Now it is time to seek answers Toshiba to resolve this detail. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: I've been using it as is since the asking of the question and yes, it does stay charged.
If its all controlled by the hardware and its only "displaying wrong" then I am so much relieved. I hope somekind of fix comes that solves this issue though, 14.04 reports everything fine.